# python isdigit() function return true for non digit character u'\u2466'

Tags: python, unicode, digit

I come across a strange problem dealing with python isdigit function.

For example:

```
>>> a = u'\u2466'
>>> a.isdigit()
Out[1]: True
>>> a.isnumeric()
Out[2]: True
```

Why this character is a digit?

Any way to make this return False instead, thanks?

---

Edit, If I don't want to treat it as a digit, then how to filter it out?

For example, when I try to convert it to a int:

```
>>> int(u'\u2466')
```

Then `UnicodeEncodeError` happened.

Comment: ⑦ is a digit, at least Unicode consortium thinks so. If you have your own understanding of "digits", feel free to share.

Comment: What values do you want to treat as digits?  If you don't agree with the way `isdigit` treats unicode and just want to look for arabic numerals, you're best off doing `if a in "0123456789"`.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

U+2466 is the [CIRCLED DIGIT SEVEN](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2466/index.htm) (⑦), so yes, it's a digit.

If your definition of what is a digit differs from that of the [Unicode Consortium](http://unicode.org/), you might have to write your own `isdigit()` method.

> Edit, If I don't want to treat it as a digit, then how to filter it out?

If you are just interested in the ASCII digits `0`...`9`, you could do something like:

```
In [4]: s = u'abc 12434 \u2466 5 def'

In [5]: u''.join(c for c in s if '0' <= c <= '9')
Out[5]: u'124345'
```

Comment: Or just `a in string.digits`.

Answer (score 9):

If you're going to convert something to `int` you need [`isdecimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#unicode.isdecimal) rather than `isdigit`.

Note that "decimal" is not just 0, 1, 2, ... 9, there are [number of characters](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm) that can be interpreted as decimal digits and converted to an integer. Example:

```
#coding=utf8

s = u"1٢٣٤5"
print s.isdecimal() # True
print int(s) # 12345
```

Answer (score 4):

The character is the `CIRCLED DIGIT SEVEN`, which is numeric and a digit.

If you want to restrict the digits to the usual 0-9, use a regular expression:

```
import re

def myIsDigit(s):
  return re.search("[^0-9]", s) is None
```