# How to determine whether string is a number when the number is negative

Tags: python

I get the following result:

```
>>> x = '-15'
>>> print x.isdigit()
False
```

When I expect it to be `True`. There seems to be no built in function that returns `True` for a string of negative number. What is the recommend to detect it?

Comment: *Only* negative numbers, or all kinds? Integers and/or floats?

Comment: a regex solution: `-?\d+`

Comment: "There seems to be ***no built in*** function that returns True for a string of negative number."  Actually, `bool("-123") == True`, but I'm pretty sure you're looking for something else...

Comment: @TokenMacGuy Yeah. `bool()` does not work for me here, because I still need to watch out for alphabets.

Comment: @Mark not exactly that simple! Look at my version down there!

Comment: @PeterVaro: Without further specifications it is :-)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python's isdigit() method returns False for negative numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15720176/pythons-isdigit-method-returns-false-for-negative-numbers)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The recommended way would be to `try` it:

```
try:
    x = int(x)
except ValueError:
    print "{} is not an integer".format(x)
```

If you also expect decimal numbers, use `float()` instead of `int()`.

Comment: @sasha.sochka: I'm not sure if the author wants `"123"` to be false.

Comment: I'm not sure OP necessarily wants negative numbers only.

Comment: @arshajii: I can't think of any. Can you give me an example?

Comment: @sasha.sochka I am not sure what you meant, but Tim understood my question right.

Comment: @TimPietzcker your approach is exactly the way I thought of it. But I come from a school of thought that tries to avoid the usage of exception when possible.

Comment: @TimPietzcker Sorry, I meant the reverse. e.g. `int('+42')` works but `'+42'.isdigit()` returns `False`. Not sure if that matters here.

Comment: @Forethinker: In Python, use of exceptions is explicitly encouraged. As miko linked to, it's easier to ask forgiveness than permission. It's even [faster in many cases](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1835844/20670) than an `if/else` construction.

Comment: @TimPietzcker the only situation I can think of is that as `str.isdigit()` is locale-dependant, it's possible that it'd return True for certain characters that `int()` wouldn't be able to work with... Other than that, I'm out of ideas as to Arshajii's statement

Comment: @TimPietzcker Thanks for confirming the most pythonic way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There might be a more elegant Python way, but a general method is to check if the first character is `'-'`, and if so, call `isdigit` on the 2nd character onward.

Comment: You want [`isdecimal`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10604236/1763356) on Python 3 or on Python 2's `unicode`.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe regex is an overhead here, but this could catch `+` and `-` before a number, and also could catch `float` and `int` as well:

*(based on @Mark's comment)*

**CODE:**

```
import re

def isdigit(string):
    return bool(re.match(r'[-+]?(?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)', string))
```

**DEMO:**

```
print isdigit('12')       # True
print isdigit('-12')      # True
print isdigit('aa')       # False
print isdigit('1a2a')     # False
print isdigit('-12-12')   # False
print isdigit('-12.001')  # True
print isdigit('+12.001')  # True
print isdigit('.001')     # True
print isdigit('+.001')    # True
print isdigit('-.001')    # True
print isdigit('-.')       # False
```

Comment: You're matching a pipe at the start. You can't "or" in a character-set. `isdigit('|12') # True`

Comment: You also missed a case: `isdigit('.5') # False`

Comment: Fixed both @Mark, thanks! The first was mistyping, the second was.. well, I forgot that case:)

Comment: You've still got it wrong. `isdigit('-.') # True`. You have to split out the cases; `[+-](?:\d+(?:\.\d*)?|\.\d+)$`

Comment: @Mark Huhh.. now that is long — not complicated, but too long :/ Anyway, thanks for the reflections! ;)

Comment: Indeed. Hence why I only did `-?\d+` in my original comment :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use `lstrip`:

```
>>> negative_number = "-1"
>>> negative_number.lstrip('-').isnumeric()
True

>>> positive_number = "2"
>>> positive_number.lstrip('-').isnumeric()
True
```

Comment: Nice! This is a succinct solution.