# Find Integers in list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list like this, named x (which I have already split):

```
['16','bob','2440', '34']
```

I want to write a code that checks to see if any of the numbers are negative. The code I tried does not work. This is what I have tried:

```
for num in x:
    if num < 0:
        print ("Negative number")
```

Comment: see the function try_parse_int https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2262333/is-there-a-built-in-or-more-pythonic-way-to-try-to-parse-a-string-to-an-integer

Answer (score 6):

Your list contains only strings. So you should cast them to floats (or integers, whatever you need) first:

```
a = ['"16','bob','2440', '-2', '34"']
for x in a:
    try:
        if float (x) < 0: print ('negative')
    except: continue
```

EDIT: I changes `int` to `float` as OP is asking for numbers and not exclusively integers.

Comment: Possibly also removing the spurious quotes. or splitting better in the first place.

Comment: There I am not sure where OP's data comes from. Maybe `"16` is a valid element, but surely no integer.

Answer (score 3):

You need to turn your numbers into integers first; use a predicate function to try to do this:

```
def negative(string):
    try:
        return int(string.strip('"')) < 0
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

The predicate function here also removes quotes; your input list looks like it was not cleaned up properly and you may want to do so *first* before testing for negative values.

Then use that to test for negative values:

```
negative_values = [v for v in a if negative(v)]
```

or test if there are *any* negative values:

```
if any(negative(v) for v in a):
    print "No negative values please!"
```

Comment: Or using Martijn's code, to check if a negative number is contained (which I think is what OP is looking for): `any (negative (x) for x in a)`

Answer (score 2):

How about checking for `-` sign in the beginning of an item and for the rest of an item to consist of digits? One-liner:

```
>>> a = ["-1", "aa", "3"]
>>> any(s.startswith('-') and s[1:].isdigit() for s in a)
True
```

Using `any`, because you've said that you `want to write a code that checks to see if any of the numbers are negative`.

Note: if there can be negative floats, then just replace `s[1:]` with `s[1:].replace(".", "")`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Interesting approach, but depending on OP's input data, this could give unwanted results such as the problem documented in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604074/python-isdigit-function-return-true-for-non-digit-character-u-u2466 (though this could also be desirable, so +1 for that).

Comment: Thank you, good point. Yeah, trying `int()` or `float()` may be safer.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to understand that neither '"16' nor '2440' are numbers - they are strings.

Secondly, you need to figure out what you want to do with '"16' - it doesn't represent a number, but I assume you want it to. You could alter these strings, but you should probably just use an appropriate method of splitting in the first place.

That said, you can do this:

```
x = ['"16','bob','2440', '34"']

def int_is_negative(s)
    try:    
       return int(s) < 0
    except ValueError:
       return False

is_negative_num = [int_is_negative(s) for s in x]
```