# Read lines starting with numbers

Tags: python, list, readfile, file-handling

How can I only read lines in a file that start with numbers in python i.e

```
Hello World <--ignore
Lovely day
blah43 
blah
1234 <--read
blah12 <--ignore
blah 
3124 <--read
Not matter how many words there are <--ignore
blah 
0832 8423984 234892304 8239048324 8023948<--read
blah132 <--ignore
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import re
with open("filename") as f:
    for line in f:
        if re.match(r"^\d+.*$",line):
            print line
```

Comment: Edit to use [the `with` statement to open the file](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lRaKmobSXF4), as is best practice.

Answer (score 5):

you can use [`isdigit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.isdigit) function :

```
for line in open('f.txt','r'):
   if line[0].isdigit():
       print line
```

Comment: Note that `isdigit()` has what might be a surprising definition of a digit, which may or may not be valid for the use case at hand. It includes all the numbers you would expect, but also [some unicode characters you might not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10604074/python-isdigit-function-return-true-for-non-digit-character-u-u2466).

Comment: isdigit is used for test that a string start with a number ?

Comment: @Hacketo When applied to the first character, as here, yes.

Comment: @Hacketo  `isdigit()` Return true if all characters in the string are digits and there is at least one character, false otherwise